# I'm trying to determine the number of digits to the left and the right of the result by...(Java)

Tags: java, math

using Double.toString(result), indexOf('.') to find the position of the decimal, and length() to find the length. This is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FormulaEvaluator {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      double x;
      double discriminant, result;

      Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter a value for x: ");
      x = userInput.nextDouble();
      discriminant = 8 * Math.pow(x, 4) - (6 * Math.pow(x, 3)) 
         + +(4 * Math.pow(x, 2)) + Math.abs(20 * x) + 1;
      result = Math.pow(9 * Math.pow(x, 3) + (7 * Math.pow(x, 2)) 
         + +(5 * x) + 3, 2) * Math.sqrt(discriminant); 

      System.out.println("Result: " + result);
   }
}
```

Comment: So what's your question? And I don't see any `Double.toString(result), indexOf('.')` in your code...

Comment: I cant figure out how and where to use those in order to get the number of digits to the left and right of the decimal point. Sorry should of been clearer.

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to know ?

Comment: How do I user Double.toString(result), indexOf('.'), and length() to find the number of digits to the left and right of the decimal point. For example, when the user inputs "1" as the x value, Result: 2992.98379547902 is the answer. I want to know how can I find the amount of digits to the left and right of the decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

First get the length of result.

```
int resultLength = Double.toString(result).length();
```

Then get the index of the decimal point.

```
int decimalIndex = Double.toString(result).indexOf('.');
```

Then subtract the index from the result length to get the number of decimal places after the decimal.

```
int numPlacesAfterDecimal = resultLength - decimalIndex;
```

The index of the decimal place happens to be the number of places to the left of the decimal.

```
int numPlacesBeforeDecimal = decimalIndex;
```

Edit: Edited variable names for better consistency.

Comment: @EricSchwob if the answer helped you, mark it as answer by ticking the tick mark so answers can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to know the count of decimal and non-decimal digits of the result variable. If that is the problem, I suggest using BigDecimal, since Double uses the scientific notation for big numbers and would make it harder to count the digits. Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x;
    double discriminant, result;

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a value for x: ");
    x = userInput.nextDouble();
    discriminant = 8 * Math.pow(x, 4) - (6 * Math.pow(x, 3)) + +(4 * Math.pow(x, 2)) + Math.abs(20 * x) + 1;
    result = Math.pow(9 * Math.pow(x, 3) + (7 * Math.pow(x, 2)) + +(5 * x) + 3, 2) * Math.sqrt(discriminant);

    BigDecimal res = BigDecimal.valueOf(result);
    String resText = String.valueOf(res);
    String[] split = resText.split("\\.");
    int countLeft = split[0].length();
    int countRight = split[1].length();

    System.out.println("Result: " + resText);
    System.out.println("Digits left: " + countLeft);
    System.out.println("Digits right: " + countRight);

}
```

Edit: Actually, BigDecimal also uses scientific notation for very big numbers. Your best bet would be to extract the part of the scientific notation and count the extra digits. For example, the number 1.3198218609483648E+33, you would have to split the part after the E+ and add that number to the count of digits.

Edit2: Here you go, an updated version for the case of scientific notation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x;
    double discriminant, result;

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a value for x: ");
    x = userInput.nextDouble();
    discriminant = 8 * Math.pow(x, 4) - (6 * Math.pow(x, 3)) + +(4 * Math.pow(x, 2)) + Math.abs(20 * x) + 1;
    result = Math.pow(9 * Math.pow(x, 3) + (7 * Math.pow(x, 2)) + +(5 * x) + 3, 2) * Math.sqrt(discriminant);

    BigDecimal res = BigDecimal.valueOf(result);
    String resText = String.valueOf(res);
    String[] split = resText.split("\\.");
    int countLeft = split[0].length();
    int countRight = 0;
    if(split[1].contains("E+")) {
        String[] splitScientificPart = split[1].split("E+");
        countRight = splitScientificPart[0].length();
        countRight += Integer.parseInt(splitScientificPart[1]);
    } else {
        countRight = split[1].length();
    }

    System.out.println("Result: " + resText);
    System.out.println("Digits left: " + countLeft);
    System.out.println("Digits right: " + countRight);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
String[] resultAsArr = (result + "").split(".");
int sizeLeft = resultAsArr[0].length();
int sizeRight = resultAsArr[1].length();
```